# String Reverse Confusion in java - String - StringBulider

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

```
String str="inputstring";
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(str);
String rev=sb.reverse().toString();
//System.out.println(sb+" "+rev);             //this prints the same reverse text
if(rev.equals(sb))
  System.out.println("Equal");
else
  System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

When I print this code StringBuilder and String prints the same output as **"gnirtstupni gnirtstupni"**, but when I checked whether they are equal using **if** condition they print **"Not Equal"**.

This is really confusing, please explain.

Comment: `rev` is a `String`.  `sb` is a `StringBuffer`.  They are two different things.

Comment: Try `rev.equals(sb.toString())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a **String** and a **StringBuilder** object. That will never lead to an *equal* result! The fact that the StringBuilder currently contains the same content as some string doesn't matter!

In other words: assume you got an egg and an egg in a box. Is that box (containing an egg) "equal" to that other egg?!

Theoretically the `StringBuilder` class could @Override the `equals()` method to specially check if it is equal to another string. But that would be rather confusing. Because if you would do that, you end up with:

```
new StringBuilder("a").equals("a") // --> true
```

giving a different result than:

```
"a".equals(new StringBuilder("a")) // --> false
```

Finally: `StringBuilder` uses the implementation for `equals()` inherited from java.lang.Object. And this implementation is simply doing a "this == other" check.

Comment: Unless you do `egg.equals(eggInBox.toEgg())`, they are not.

Comment: More than just confusing; it's forbidden by the spec.

Comment: @shmosel Well, you could then @ Override String.equals() too . But I hope the message *bad idea* comes over already.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` and `String` are two different classes, so objects of those types should never equal one another, regardless of their content.

Comment: You seem to be implying that objects of different types can't be equal to each other as a rule, which isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` and `String` are different objects,

But if you want check equal by string. just use `toString()`

```
    if(rev.equals(sb.toString()))
      System.out.println("Equal");
    else
      System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

Answer (score 1):

`rev` is a String.

`sb` is a StringBuilder.

They are two different things, and thus will never be equal.